# How to add app name after port in tomcat 8? (E.g localhost:8080/myapp/login.html rather than localhost:8080/login.html)

Tags: java, tomcat8

So I tried couple of things, the one that seemed to work was adding context tag with docBase and path to conf/server.xml file, within the host tag.

It worked with one context. However, I want to add multiple applications, e.g.

- localhost:8080/test/login.html
- localhost:8080/live/login.html

I duplicated the ROOT folder inside webapps and changed the name. So far, it is going ok, but some requests like the background image of the login page are still being fetched from root (e.g. http://localhost:8080/images/bg.png)

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have 2 apps, why don't you deploy test.war and live.war seperately ? Are you modifying ROOT.war ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply... Kindly bare with me as I am not expert in this.
I didn't deploy any war files. I started working on the ROOT directory and modified the index.html there. I thought that if I needed to have a different context, it would be as simple as duplicating the ROOT folder with a different name in webapps. The URL is working properly and the login page is displayed, yet, some items are still being fetched from ROOT like the background image and CSS.

What do I need to do? Is exporting .war file the solution? If so, I can look it up.